# Jboss - configure with Access-Control-Allow-Origin *

Tags: ajax, xss, jboss5.x

I'm new to jboss and was wondering if it's possible to configure with Access-Control-Allow-Origin *. Is this possible? If so, where does this directive go? Am I better off just using nginx as a proxy?

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 0):

You could write a servlet filter, stick it in web.xml for your app, and deply it to jboss. That would at least work for that app.